# Opening a large pickle file causes MemoryError even though memory is available

Tags: python, pickle

I have a large pickle file, 5 GB. When attempting to load it, I get thrown a `MemoryError`. My system has 32 GB of RAM. 5 GB is in use before attempting to load the pickle. **10 GB is still available when the error is thrown**, and no swap is used. What could be the cause of this? It is a 64 bit system with a 64 bit Python installation.

Is there any way to get the file split up, or read in a memory mapped way so that I can split it up myself?

The structure of the data inside the pickle is `List[Dict[str, str]]`. I'm attempting to load it as follows:

```
with open(path, "rb") as fil:
    data = pickle.load(fil)
```

It's a Linux system, Fedora 33 64-bit, with 32 GB RAM and 20 GB swap. There is always way more than 10 GB RAM available and all of the 20 GB swap. Python is version 3.9.4 from Anaconda.

Comment: Can you post the code that is raising the MemoryError?

Comment: @BlastOffBronze Yes.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394768/pickle-file-too-large-to-load/26395638 You should be able to find the solution there